# How to store the input of Nodejs to Database

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have created basic HTML form and made it too display on the console I have also created a database using nodejs How do I connect the server.js to database.js? 
My HTML file

```
  <html>
   <body>
       <header className = "App-header" >
              <h1 className = "App-title" > Registration Form </h1>
        </header>
          <form action = "http://127.0.0.1:8081/process_get" method = "get">
              <label>
                <p>First Name:
                    <input type="text" name="first_name" /></p>
                <p>Last Name:
                    <input type="text" name="last_name" /></p>
                <p>Password:
                    <input type="password" name="password" /></p>
                <p>Mobile Number:
                    <input type="number" name="user_mobile" /></p>
                <p>Address:
                    <input type="text" name="user_address" /></p>
              </label>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
          </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

My server.js file

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.get('/index.htm', function (req, res) {
   res.sendFile( __dirname + "/" + "index.htm" );
})

app.get('/process_get', function (req, res) {
   // Prepare output in JSON format
   response = {
      first_name:req.query.first_name,
      lastname:req.query.last_name,
      password:req.query.password,
      mobile:req.query.user_mobile,
      address:req.query.user_address
   };
   console.log(response);
   res.end(JSON.stringify(response));
})
```

My databasejs file

```
    var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "127.0.0.1",
  user: "root",
  password: "",
  database: "react"
});

con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected!");
  /*Create a table named "customers":*/
  var sql = "CREATE TABLE form (firstname VARCHAR(255),lastname VARCHAR(255),mobile INT,password VARCHAR(15), address VARCHAR(255))";
  con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Table created");
  });
});
```

How do I store all the receiving input to store in database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you have to import or require you databasejs file to your server.js. or you can do  this somewhere else also.

```
var db = require('path to databasejs ');
```

then inside your route.

```
app.get('/process_get', function (req, res) {
     // Prepare output in JSON format
     response = {
         first_name: req.query.first_name
         , lastname: req.query.last_name
         , password: req.query.password
         , mobile: req.query.user_mobile
         , address: req.query.user_address
     };
     query = db.query("insert query", [params]
         , (err, result) => {
             res.end(JSON.stringify(response));
         })

 })
```